# How can I change the size of a CustomItem inside a form in J2ME?

Tags: mobile, java-me, midp, lcdui

How can I change the size of a `CustomItem` inside a form in J2ME? I created a `CustomItem` (derived  class of `javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem`) and placed it inside a form (of derived class of `javax.microedition.lcdui.Form`). After some event triggers, I want to change the `CustomItem`'s height and width. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. We should create a new object for the new CustomItem with new properties.Then delete the existing CustomItem from the form and add the new CustomItem inside the form.

Answer (score 2):

In MIDP, CustomItem is rendered by the enclosing container, the Form. MIDP doesn't provide a way to notify it's parent that it's size has changed; so this behavior has to be handcrafted in your code.

Suppose your event is fired upon the user pressing OK (FIRE), then you will need to call either repaint() OR repaint(x,y,w,h). This repaint call causes either entire CustomItem to be painted or just the rectangular portion. This inturn calls your paint() method (of CustomItem) where you can draw a larger sized component.

Comment: Hi Kiran Kuppa, I createa a table using CustomItem inside a form in J2ME I created a CustomItem (derived class of javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem).If user clicks ok button present in the table then how should i expand the table with respect to height and width

Comment: Shiva, could you please post your code? It is easier for me to modify your code and show you how it is done; We all are hard pressed for time.